# Bitsrc eject component if there is no update to export

Tags: javascript, npm, bit-src

I'm using Bitsrc.io to manage shared components.

Sometimes it happens that I import a remote component which adds the physical files to my project. 
I then want to eject the module so that it is managed by npm again.
However I haven't made any changes so bit-cli responds with

> nothing to export

On their docs site I cannot find another reference to using the --eject flag except with the export command.

Anyone bumped into this before?

Comment: bit.dev is really good

Answer (score 1):

Right now in order to achieve this you need to run the following commands:

`bit remove id
npm install id-npm`

(*) - look in the bitsrc ui as they way id looks like in bit registry is different from npm.

if you do make changes you can do `bit export --eject` which will do remove and npm install. This command is currently being developed in the dev branch and is probably going to be available in the next release. You can also force an export if you force a tag by using --all flag or --scope. I advice against it.

Comment: an independent `ejecta command is coming soon https://github.com/teambit/bit/pull/1240